# Subversion Repo Mirroring

Tags: linux, debian, svn

We are running subversion 1.1.4-2 on debian sarge and have many repository. A repo of a client needs to be mirrored with remote server. can anyone please help me how to do that. I am very new to subversion.

Like, we have a subversion server inside firewall and a server in remover (client) place. He needs his repo which is there in our server should get synced.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.html) is the Subversion remote repository mirroring tool.